# Properties of weakly convergent series in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ given sequence of vectors from $H$. Suppose that for every $\{\alpha\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\in \ell^2$ series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\alpha_nx_n$ is weakly convergent. How to show that for every $h\in H$ series $\sum|\langle h,x_n\rangle|^2$ is convergent and there exist $c>0$ s.th. $\|\sum \alpha_nx_n\|^2\le c\sum |\alpha_n|^2$  ?

I tried to use closed graph theorem, but I had problem with finding proper operator.

Comment: Use the Uniform Boundedness Principle : For $a=(a_j)_j\in H$ and $f_n(a)=\sum_{j=0}^na_j x_j$, if $\{\|f_n\|\}_{n\in N_0}$ is unbounded then for some $y\in H$ the set $\{\|f_n(y)\|\}_{n\in N_0}$ is unbounded.

Comment: It gives me only the second part of this theorem (weakly convergent is bounded and then Uniform Boundedness Principle), but what about the first one ?